# Calling PHP name from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, forms

I'm making check list for a form that will send an email with to myself letting me know what items have been checked.

I have successful done this so far with just single inputs:

HTML:

`<input type="text" name="visitorfirst" size="35" />`

PHP:

`From: $visitorfirst \n`

This sends their name from the form to  my email fine.

What I can't manage to do is have x amount of check boxes that all have the same name e.g. `col` with seperate values and send each one selected to my email if selected.

This is what I've tried:

HTML:

```
<form action="">
 <table class="checks">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Desktop">Desktop</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Laptop">laptop</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Monitor">Monitor</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Server">Server</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Networking">Networking</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Smartphone">Smartphone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Tablet">Tablet</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Printer">Printer</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col" value="Telephone">Telephone</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
What hardware to collect: $col \n
```

How can I get the form to send multiple "checks"?

Comment: Change the name to `col[]` and check the value of `$_GET['col']` or, of you post the form, `$_POST['col']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a checkbox group you do this by adding []

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="col[]" value="Server">Server</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="col[]" value="Networking">Networking</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="col[]" value="Smartphone">Smartphone</td>
```

Your post return now returns an array so `$_POST['col']` is an array you can then foreach loop through it or implode it to a csv or serialise it or json encode it or do whatever you like with it.

(In your case probably for each to generate your email code)